# Multiple useEffect React.useEffect has missing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Products component which displays products for a category.
CategoryId is taken from route params,  and then user can paginate the products. So there is 2 useEffect one when categoryId is changed, and the other when the current page number is changed. If I use one effect with two dependencies (categoryId and currentPage), I couldn't find a way to reset the current page number to 1. (When user is in category 1 and goes to 2 page,  I want to reset the page number when category changes)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  useProductState,
  useProductDispatch
} from "../contexts/product.context";

const Products = props => {
  const categoryId = +props.match.params.id;

  const { categoryProducts, totalCount } = useProductState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(1);

  const dispatch = useProductDispatch();

  const pageSize = 2;
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(+totalCount / pageSize);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPage(1);
    dispatch({
      type: "getPaginatedCategoryProducts",
      payload: {
        categoryId,
        pageSize,
        pageNumber: currentPage
      }
    });
  }, [categoryId]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: "getPaginatedCategoryProducts",
      payload: {
        categoryId,
        pageSize,
        pageNumber: currentPage
      }
    });
  }, [currentPage]);

  const changePage = page => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Category {categoryId}</h1>
      {categoryProducts &&
        categoryProducts.map(p => <div key={p.id}>{p.name}</div>)}
      {pageCount > 0 &&
        Array.from({ length: pageCount }).map((p, index) => {
          return (
            <button key={index + 1} onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}>
              {index + 1}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      <br />
      currentPage: {currentPage}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two effects :

1.When `categoryId` change then set current page to 1 :

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPage(1);
  }, [categoryId]);
```

2.When `categoryId` or `currentPage` change then fetch new data :

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: "getPaginatedCategoryProducts",
      payload: {
        categoryId,
        pageSize,
        pageNumber: currentPage
      }
    });
  }, [currentPage, categoryId, dispatch]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-cartwright-jdg9j

Comment: I just noticed that when we are in category one's second page, and click category two, useEffect runs two times. Any idea prevent this?

Comment: Yeah you can force the component to reset the state when the route change like this : `<Route path="/products/:id" render={(props) => <Products key={props.match.params.id} {...props} />} />`

Comment: I mean useEffect with dispatch runs twice for page 1 and page 2,  because when categoryId changes 
it resets currentPage to 1, which again makes the useEffect run.
I don't see any relation with routing here, sorry If I didn't understand.

Comment: In the code I provided I change the `key` prop when the category Id change, this will force the `Products` component to reset the state (currentPage = 1), and so the useEffect will not trigger twice, try it ;)

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think you can keep the category in the local state of component as you are doing for page. Then you can check if the local state matches the Redux state or not. If not, you can reset the page number and set the new category or else only change the page number if required. The other useEffect might not be working on category change because it is not a local state change and useEffect is only triggered on local state change. Here is an example that might help

```
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if(categoryId!==currentCategory){
        dispatch({
           type: "getPaginatedCategoryProducts",
           payload: {
           categoryId,
           pageSize,
           pageNumber: 1
        }
        });
        }
        else{
        dispatch({
           type: "getPaginatedCategoryProducts",
           payload: {
           categoryId,
           pageSize,
           pageNumber: currentPage
        }
        });
        }
        }, [categoryId,currentPage]);
```

I hope you can understand and the answer is helpful.

Comment: Thank you Bilal, the accepted answer seems to be right way.

Comment: Yes you are right. I would appreciate if you can upvote. Thanks!