# reset to first page if another filter is changed with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using react functional components.

To call data from an api , there are available filters and pagination. When I change a filter type, the pagination has to return to the first page.

```
const pageChange = (page) => {
        setPage(page);
    };

 useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const dateFilter = start && end ? `start=${start}&end=${end}` : null;
            const pageFilter = `offset=${
        (page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE
      }&limit=${ITEMS_PER_PAGE}`;
            const defaultFilters = `${dateFilter?dateFilter:''}${dateFilter?'&':''}${pageFilter}`;
            let request = null;
            switch (type) {
                case "upcoming":
                    request = fetchUpcomingLaunches(defaultFilters);
                    break;
                case "successful":
                    request = fetchLaunches(`${defaultFilters}&launch_success=true`);
                    break;
                case "failed":
                    request = fetchLaunches(`${defaultFilters}&launch_success=false`);
                    break;
                default:
                    request = fetchLaunches(defaultFilters);
                    break;
            }
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const response = await request;
                setItems(getItems(response.data));
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (err) {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [start, end, type, page]);
```

Im using material ui pagination :

```
   <Pagination
          count={20}
          variant="outlined"
          shape="rounded"
          size="large"
          page={page}
          onChange={(event, val) => pageChange(val)}
        />
```

Here the start, end and type are filters . If any of there filters changes, the api has to be called and the data should be refreshed. The api has to return the paginated response based on the page . My problem is that when any of the other filters are changed , the page should reset to the first page and data should be loaded from the first page. Is it possible to use two useEffect hooks? I have tried useEffect with type, start, end dependecies . As of now the api is getting called two times as  setPage is called again.

Comment: I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773502/multiple-useeffect-react-useeffect-has-missing-dependencies) when I was new to react. Check the codesandbox in the answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah viewed it , i dont get how it will prevent useEffct being called twice

Comment: It seems your question is a bit of different from mine.

Comment: @SuleymanSah true.Actually this issue will be fixed if we can get the total count of items from backend . the Pagination component will handle it

Comment: This can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240169/skip-first-useeffect-when-there-are-multiple-useeffects

Comment: If you can add it as an answer to this based on my question, I think it will help others too @SuleymanShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add a new useEffect with filter dependencies, and take advantage of [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to  prevent the api being called two times when a filter changes.

Idea taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240169/skip-first-useeffect-when-there-are-multiple-useeffects)

```js
const isFilterApplied = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Filter change effect")
    isFilterApplied.current = true;
    setCurrentPage(1);
  }, [start, end, type]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const dateFilter = start && end ? `start=${start}&end=${end}` : null;
      const pageFilter = `offset=${(page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE}&limit=${ITEMS_PER_PAGE}`;
      const defaultFilters = `${dateFilter ? dateFilter : ""}${dateFilter ? "&" : ""}${pageFilter}`;
      let request = null;
      switch (type) {
        case "upcoming":
          request = fetchUpcomingLaunches(defaultFilters);
          break;
        case "successful":
          request = fetchLaunches(`${defaultFilters}&launch_success=true`);
          break;
        case "failed":
          request = fetchLaunches(`${defaultFilters}&launch_success=false`);
          break;
        default:
          request = fetchLaunches(defaultFilters);
          break;
      }
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await request;
        setItems(getItems(response.data));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }

    if (isFilterApplied.current && currentPage !== 1) {
      return;
    }

    console.log("Main effect")

    fetchData();
  }, [start, end, type, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);
  }, [start, end, type]);

  const changePage = (page) => {
    isFilterApplied.current = false;
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };
```

A sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-haze-4v9ds?file=/src/components/Products.jsx) with a different code base if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

after filter changed, you can setPage to page 1 and add setPage in useEffect with condition filter. for example

```
useEffect(() => {
   setPage(1);
},[start, end])
```

Comment: I have tried this, in this case the api will call two times in the first Useeffect and data will be affected based on which request will return the response first

Comment: @MohitHarshan I don't think this second useEffect causes the api being called two times. There must be some other reason, if you can provide a basic version of your app in codesandbox, it would be easy to find the reason.

Comment: Yes, for example , the dependecy start changes , the api useeffct will be called because it depends on start, , when setPage is called in first useEffect, it will call second useEffect again @SuleymanSah